# admin.credential.applicationDefault() errors when testing Firebase Cloud Function on build server: Could not refresh access token

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, travis-ci, firebase-admin

I have an automated test that runs the cloud function locally, signs in as an admin, and writes data to Firestore. Previously it has worked great with non-admin permissions, and now we are upgrading the cloud function to have admin permissions. I can run the test fine locally, and I can serve the function locally and hit it with Postman and it works fine.

However, when running on our build server (Travis CI - paid) the function throws an error: `14 UNAVAILABLE: Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: Could not refresh access token`.

This is the first test that signs in, so it would be unexpected to already have an access token that is being refreshed.

Locally, I have signed in to firebase using `firebase login`. I have already exported a login token for Travis using `firebase login:ci` and `travis encrypt`.

Any thoughts on why we see this error on Travis and not locally?

Here is the stack trace:

`14 UNAVAILABLE: Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: Could not refresh access token.
      at Object.<anonymous>.exports.createStatusError (node_modules/google-gax/node_modules/grpc/src/common.js:87:15)
      at Object.onReceiveStatus (node_modules/google-gax/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1188:28)
      at InterceptingListener.Object.<anonymous>.InterceptingListener._callNext (node_modules/google-gax/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:564:42)
      at InterceptingListener.Object.<anonymous>.InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (node_modules/google-gax/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:614:8)
      at callback (node_modules/google-gax/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:841:24)`

I am initializing Firebase with:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp({
            'credential': admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
            'databaseURL': firebaseConfig.databaseURL
        });
```

Answer (score 6):

[Application Default Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production) (ADC) do not support Firebase login tokens (regardless of what you mean by that). For ADC to work in a dev/test environment, you should have one of the following things configured:

1. Have a service account JSON file in the file system with the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable pointing to it.
2. Have a `~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json` file with a valid refresh token configuration. This file is usually managed by the `gcloud` and `firebase` CLIs.

Local Functions emulator creates the file in (2), which is why the code works locally. You have to have one of the above configured for Travis.